# Create a rolled up week column using the day column and populate the value with first monday of the week: Snowflake database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake Database:
I have a day level table , i am trying use the day column to create a week column with the value of first Monday's of the week as a week value using following function. even though the table have a data for all seven days ( Monday through Sunday ) of the week. The following function will create a week column with five working days ( Monday through Friday) only rolled up to a week leaving Saturday and Sunday. is there any function which i can use to grab all seven days of data under one week in SNOWFLAKE DATABASE (first monday of the week).

CURRENT FUNCTION USED:
select dateadd('day', (extract('dayofweek_iso', current_date()) * -1) +1 , current_date() );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake provides [DATE_TRUNC()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) to roll up date to corresponding year/month/week/day.

For the mentioned use case following query will roll up to Monday of the week.

```
select date_trunc('WEEK',current_date()) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake [last_day()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_day.html) function can be used to achieve that. You can easily get the last day of week (Sunday) and subtract 6 days to get the first day of that week (Monday) like that:

```
select last_day(current_date(), 'week')-6 as first_day_of_week;
```